# Javascript for calculating Quiz score in SCORM1.2

Tags: javascript, xhtml, cdata, scorm, scorm1.2

I have a SCORM 1.2 content package which has some HTML pages containing quiz questions. After clicking on the submit button the javascript calculates the score and returns back. My current java script works fine for two questions and if I've more questions in one page then I have to modify the javascript by including a new variable. I want to know is there any general way to write the same javascript for 'n' questions;which could calculate the score irrespective of changes in the number of questions. Thanking you.

**My Java Script:(calculate.js)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
var numQuestions = 2;
var rawScore = 0;
var actualScore = 0;
var question0;
var question1;
var key0 = 0;
var key1 = 1;
function getAnswer()
        {
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.id","key0b8");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.type","choice");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                          "0");

            for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if (document.getElementById("quizForm8").key0b8[i].checked)
               {
                  question0 = document.getElementById("quizForm8").key0b8[i].value;
                  doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.student_response",question0);
                  break;
               }
            }

            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.id","key1b8");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.type","choice");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                          "1");

            for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if (document.getElementById("quizForm8").key1b8[i].checked)
               {
                  question1 = document.getElementById("quizForm8").key1b8[i].value;
                  doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.student_response",question1);
                  break;
               }
            }

           }
        function calcRawScore(){

            if (question0 == key0)
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.result","correct");
               rawScore++;
            }
            else
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.result","wrong");
            }
            if (question1 == key1)
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.result","correct");
               rawScore++;
            }
            else
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.result","wrong");
            }
        }

        function calcScore2()
        {
           computeTime();  // the student has stopped here.

           document.getElementById("quizForm8").submitB.disabled = true;

           getAnswer();

           calcRawScore();

           actualScore = Math.round(rawScore / numQuestions * 100);
        alert("Your score is " + actualScore + "%")   

           doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.score.raw", actualScore+"" );

           var mode = doLMSGetValue( "cmi.core.lesson_mode" );

               if ( mode != "review"  &&  mode != "browse" ){
                 if ( actualScore < 50 )
                 {
                   doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.lesson_status", "failed" );
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                   doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.lesson_status", "passed" );
                 }

                 doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.exit", "" );
                 } 

         exitPageStatus = true;


         doLMSCommit();

         doLMSFinish();

        }
]]>
</script>
```

**(X)HTML Page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <!-- Other Code -->
      <body>
        <div id="outer">
          <div class="QuizTestIdevice" id="id8">
            <script src="calculate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <form name="quizForm8" id="quizForm8" action="javascript:calcScore2();">
              <div class="iDevice_inner">
                <div class="passrate" value="50"></div>
                <div class="question">
                  <div id="taquestion0b8">
                    1&gt; TEXT FOR QUESTION 1.
                  </div><br />
                  True<input type="radio" name="key0b8" value="0" id="taoptionAnswer0q0b8" /> 
                  False<input type="radio" name="key0b8" value="1" id="taoptionAnswer1q0b8" />
                </div><br />
                <div class="question">
                  <div id="taquestion1b8">
                    2&gt; TEXT FOR QUESTION 2.
                  </div><br />
                  True<input type="radio" name="key1b8" value="0" id="taoptionAnswer0q1b8" /> 
                  False<input type="radio" name="key1b8" value="1" id="taoptionAnswer1q1b8" />
                </div><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submitB" value="SUBMIT ANSWERS" />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the question count value on function call

```
<form name="quizForm8" id="quizForm8" action="javascript:calcScore2();">
```

to

```
<form name="quizForm8" id="quizForm8" action="javascript:calcScore2(5);"> //5 -> Argument for 5 questions
```

-

```
function calcScore2(n)
{ 
    numQuestions = n;
.
.
```